# How to connect Python to Microsoft Access database file?

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am trying to connect Python to a Microsoft Access database file, but I keep getting this error:

> 64bit and Office 365 Business 64bit (Access).

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=[path];')
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)

import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=[path];')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from username_pw')

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print (row)
```

Comment: Are you running 32bit perhaps ?

Comment: Check the list returned by `pyodbc.drivers()` to see what drivers are available to your Python app.

Comment: here is reference, you can test. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233912/connecting-sqlalchemy-to-msaccess

Comment: It returns ['SQL Server'] - Gord Thompson

Comment: So the Access ODBC driver is not available to your Python app. However, if the list shows *just* 'SQL Server' then it suggests that you are running 64-bit Python because the list would be much longer if you were running 32-bit Python. Are you sure that you are running 64-bit Office?

Comment: Yes, 'Microsoft Access for Office 365 MS (16.0.11901.20204) 64-bit'

Comment: You may need to manually install the 64-bit version of the ODBC driver. See [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/cannot-use-odbc-or-oledb) for details.